# Search for pattern and print sub-directory and the total count side by side

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

I am having a directory called **out**, and in that directory I am having 20 sub-directories and each sub-directory name will be ending with **_f** and also will be having a file called **report.txt**.
Below is the **report.txt** for one sub-directory and sub-directory name is **first**:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5
spent       23          32          23          32
Done        76          87          98          76
Listed      87          78          56          98
Total       186         197         177         206
```

We dont need to sum up anything, total count will be already printed there it self in the **report.txt** file, I need to print the output as below for one sub-directory(**first**) as below.

Output Syntax:

```
Sub-directory name:  Count(Column 4)
```

Output:

```
First: 177
```

I tried this code but not getting the exact solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Thesereports are based on this directory:" ; pwd
echo " " ;
File="report.txt"
for d in *_f;
do
echo "$d:";
awk '/Total/{print "Total no of warnings:" $(NF-1);exit}' "$d"/"$File"
done
```

Comment: "each sub-directory name will be **ending with _f**" and "sub-directory name is **first**" don't agree with each other. Did you mean "sub-directory name is first**_f**" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this loop.

```
for f in *_f/report.txt; do
    cnt=$( awk '/^Total/{print $4}' "$f" )
    printf "%s:\t%s\n" "${f%_*}" "$cnt"
done
```

I assumed subdirs are named like `first_f`, `second_f` etc, so we print lines like:

```
first:   177
second:   42
```

You can add any other text around with [printf](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf).

Comment: @thanasip can you please explain the printf line...?

Comment: I have also added a link for `printf` to see more details. The first argument is a string to print, where spaceholders exist, for example `%s` means "wait for a string there". The rest of the arguments, are variables that `printf` will use to replace these spaceholders.

Comment: The first variable to print is variable `$f{%_*}` which means to cut the substring from last `_` to the end and keep the first part of this string. The second argument is the output of the `awk` command, calculated in previous line.

Comment: @thanasip If we do not want to cut the substring from last _ , then we can just use like this : **printf "%s:\t%s\n" "${f}" "$cnt"**

Comment: yes, right. this would include `reports.txt` also. If you want only the subdir, it is `${f%/*}`, see more about parameter expansion, https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get this done in a single `awk` command:

```
awk '/^Total/{f=FILENAME; sub(/_.*/, "", f); print f ":\t" $4}' *_f/report.txt
```

```
first:  177
second: 142
```